What does the phase of the complex derivative evaluated at a point tell you?
I am learning the method of stationary phase/saddle point method for approximating integrals like $\int_C f(z) e^{x g(z)}dz$ for complex $f(z)$ and $g(z)=\phi(x,y) + i \psi(x,y)$ as the real parameter $x$ tends to infinity. The method involves finding the places where $g'(z_0)=0$ which are (by the maximum modulus principle), saddle points in the real and imaginary components of $g(z)$. We wish to find the path of steepest descent in $\phi(x,y)$ (which corresponds to a path of constant $\psi(x,y)$) and we do so by writing the second derivative of $g(z)$ and writing this in amplitude phase form at the point $z_0$: $g''(z_0) = re^{i \theta}$.
We are then told, and if I spent a little longer puzzling over the notes I expect I could show, that the path of steepest descent of $\phi(x,y)$ through $z_0$ occurs at angle $\varphi = \frac{\pi - \theta}{2}$.
This is quite useful, but I'll admit, I am surprised that the formula to get $\varphi$ from $\theta$ is so non-trivial. If not encoding the information about the path of steepest descent (or ascent), what does $\theta$ represent? In particular, I am surprised by the fact $\varphi$ is proportional to $\theta/2$?
Put simply, given a stationary point of the complex function $g(z)$ such that $g'(z_0)$ what does the phase of $g''(z_0)$ tell you about the stationary point?

Hadn't you better call your real parameter $x$ something else, since you're also using $x$ as a coordinate in $\phi(x,y)$ and $\psi(x,y)$?

(1) In the simplest possible case where $g(z)= z^2= (x^2- y^2)+ 2 i xy$
you can see  after  switching to polar coordinates ( where $z= r e^{i \theta}$ )  that $g(z)= r^2 (\cos 2\theta +i \sin \theta)$. Thus if $t>0$ then $|e^{t g(z)}|= e^{t Re (g)} $ decays most rapidly along the ray where the factor $\cos (2\theta)= -1$ is most negative; that is in the directions where $Arg(z)=\theta =\pm \pi/2$.
(2) Next consider the slightly more complicated case where the Taylor polynomial is $g(z)= a z^2$ in which  $a\ne 0$ is complex.
This case will be reduced to the prior case by a simple change of variables.  The change of variables  $ z= bz'$  ( i.e. $z'=z/b$) converts
$g(z) = a z^2 = ab^2 (z')^2$ to simply
$g(z)= (z')^2$ (the prior case analyzed) if we choose $b$ so that   $1= ab^2$. Thus by (1), the direction of steepest descent is given by $ \pm \pi/2= Arg z' $. But $Arg z'= Arg z- Arg b$ and $Arg b= Arg(a)/2$. Thus the equation for the angle of steepest descent is $ Arg (z)= \frac {1}{2}( \pm \pi -Arg (a))$.
(3) If $g(z) =\sum_k c_k z^k$ is given by an infinite Taylor series, one can prove that if $g''(0)\ne 0$ then one can write $g(z)= (z')^2$ where $z'=h(z)$ has an infinite  Taylor expansion that begins like $z'= z/b +\ldots $ in which as above $ b^2= a$.
The  transformation  $ z\to z'$ deforms the straight ray in the $z'$ plane to a curve in the $z$ plane which is the description of the curvilinear path of steepest descent.
P.S. All of the above methods can be generalized to higher-order critical points such as those modeled by $g(z)= z^3$  etc.
